# python giving me "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" and i cant figure out why

Tags: python

i have this code:

```
board = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]


def print_board():
    for line in board:
        for char in line:
            print(char, end=" ")
        print()

print_board()

island_list = []

for y in range(len(board)):
    for x in range(len(board[y])):
        if board[y][x] == 1:
            if (y, x) not in island_list:
                if x == len(board[x]) - 1 or x == 0 or y == len(board)-1 or y == 0:
                   island_list.append((y, x))

List_to_add = []

for y in range(len(board)):
    state = 0
    for x in range(len(board[0])):
        if board[y][x] == 1 and (y, x) not in island_list or state == 1 and (y, x) not in island_list:
            List_to_add.append((y, x))
        if (y, x) in island_list:
            state = 1
        if board[y][x] == 0:
            state = 0
            List_to_add = []
        if (y, x) in island_list and board[y][x] == 1 or state == 1:
            for x in List_to_add:
                island_list.append(x)

List_to_add = []

for x in range(0, len(board[0])):
    state = 0
    for y in range(0, len(board)):
        if state == 1:
            for x in List_to_add:
                island_list.append(x)
        if board[y][x] == 1:
            List_to_add.append((y, x))
        if (y, x) in island_list:
            state = 1
        if board[y][x] == 0:
            state = 0
            List_to_add = []
        
print(island_list)
```

in this program im trying to seperate the indexes that are connected to the edges of the matrix from the ones not connected but when i try to access an index in the matrix
im getting the TypeError for line 46:  `if board[y][x] == 1:`.
i find this really weird as i used this same exact statement in a line above this one and got no error.
would appreciate some help with this issue.

Comment: You are reusing the `x` name in `for x in List_to_add:`.  After that loop finishes, `x` contains a tuple, not an integer.  Why not just replace that loop with `island_list.extend( List_to_add )`?

Comment: By the way, `and` and `or` are not equal precedence.  You should be using parentheses in statements where you mix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running loop

```
for x in range(0, len(board[0])):
    state = 0
    for y in range(0, len(board)):
        if state == 1:
            for x in List_to_add:
                island_list.append(x)
        if board[y][x] == 1:
            List_to_add.append((y, x))
        if (y, x) in island_list:
            state = 1
        if board[y][x] == 0:
            state = 0
            List_to_add = []
```

check line

```
for x in List_to_add:
```

in this line you are using x as temporary variable which at the end reinitialise x with a tuple thus creating a problem for you.

Just rename this variable.